# Relation Table on ER-diaagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am designing a databese ER-diagram using the [Chen-convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Diagramming_conventions). My question is how to distinguish a relation (association) table between two tables,  from a simple relation with a foreign key. Assuming the first case as if `TableA` has a `N:M` relation to `TableB` by creating a relational table and the second case as if `TableA` has a `1:N` relation to TableB by using a foreign key (`TableA_Id`) on `TableB`. Should I depict both cases with a diamond an merely assign the numbers of the relation on each case (either `M:N` or `1:N`), or is there a different way to depict a relation table from a foreign-key relation?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not expert in DataBase Design, only student,  but:

1:N is 1 home: N windows

Home(home, ...)
 Windows(windows, ...., home)
  (home) is foreing key of Home

M:N is M Students: N area

Student(student, ...)
 Area(area, .....)
 Exam(student, area, puctuation)
  (student) is foreing key of Student
  (area) is foreing key of Area

Well is important know that when is N:M you need a relation to can join both.
and puctuation will be an atrribute of this relation.

See you later, sorry my english isn't very goog!